# Suppress warnings in Zend Studio

Tags: php, eclipse, zend-studio, suppress-warnings

In Eclipse writing Java, it's easy to suppress warnings on some scopes, by annotating a method or variable within the IDE.

Is it possible to suppress warnings at scopes while writing PHP within Zend Studio 7.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that I know of, but in PHP you can use the [Error Control Operator](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) to suppress error messages. Mind the Warning though. This won't disable any error annotations given by Zend Studio itself. Which annotations are shown in general can be configured in *Window | Preferences | PHP | Editor | Mark Occurences*.

Java annotations like @SuppressWarnings don't work in Zend Studio or PHP because PHP does not know the concept of Annotations like Java implements them.

Answer (score 0):

Not on a section-by-section basis, though you can turn off certain warnings globally via the preferences.  Be forewarned, however, that a lot of the warnings you see in Zend Studio would actually cause compiler errors in other languages so it is a good idea to mind them.